# How to visualize nonuniform data grid as heat map (a.k.a color map)?

Tags: c++, qt, heatmap, qwt, colormap

There is a nonuniform data grid consisting of x and y coordinates and corresponding value. It needs to be represented as heat map (color map).

Key word here is **nonuniform**, meaning that values are not evenly distributed across x and y axis.

I have no issue plotting uniform data grid using qwt library. To plot heat map this library requires matrix (i.e. uniform data grid) as input:

```
[1 2 3 ]
 4 5 6
 7 8 9]
```

but it can't process nonuniform data:

```
[1 2 3
 ? ? 4
 5 6 7
 8 9 10]
```

Above is just an example and real one is much more complex.

So the question is how to represent nonuniform data grid? Should I first transform nonuniform grid to uniform one? If so, is there a standard way of doing that?

In that case ideally would be to have a function (preferably written in c++), which takes as argument nonuniform DataGrid and returns uniform DataGrid, where DataGrid is

```
struct DataGrid {
    std::vector<double> x;
    std::vector<double> y;
    std::vector<double> values;
}
```

Comment: First thought (inspired by the 3D graphics): triangulate the point cloud, then draw a mesh with color attributes for every vertex, GPU will interpolate the colors. (no qwt involved though)